# Faster ways of placing cans in the fridge?

Tags: drinks, organization

When buying soda or beer, it usually takes some time and effort in taking out the cans from the cardboard box and placing them neatly in your fridge.

Instead of just taking out one can at a time and placing it in the fridge, I've tried taking out two and three cans at a time to speed up the process but I still feel as though there might be a better way to go about this.

Is there a more efficient, faster way to place 12 pack's of soda/beer neatly in your fridge?

[image]

Comment: The two cans on top look lonely.

Comment: @SUMGUY, those cans are obviously on a date. They have left the group to get some privacy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 2x6 boxes that soda cans tend to come in, you can open one end of the box and tear the flap off that is closest to the bottom of the cans.  Put that end in first so that the cans are upright.  Next, open the other end and pull the box out with one hand while steadying the cans with your other hand.  Try not to push the cans out the end of the box, or it will get all crooked.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume the 12-pack is in a cardboard box.

1. Get a cutting board or some similar sturdy, flat rectangle.
2. Turn the 12-pack upside down on a table.
3. Tear off the bottom piece of cardboard (which is pointing at the ceiling).
4. Put the cutting board on top of the exposed can-bottoms.
5. Holding the cutting board in place with one hand, flip the 12-pack of cans over on top of it.
6. Tear the back off of the cardboard case, but keep the front and the 2 sides intact.
7. Walk them over to the fridge and put the cutting board on the shelf.
8. Slide the cutting board out from underneath the cans by putting your hand against the front of the box and pushing towards the back of the fridge.
9. Pull the cardboard box off of the cans.

The cans won't all be "staged" like they are in your photo, with labels pointing towards the front. And the width of the cutting board may prevent you from placing ALL the cans on the shelf this way (because the cutting board will bump into cans you already placed on the shelf). But at least this will let you move 12 cans at a time!

Answer (score 2):

Are you physically able to lift all of the cans in your picture at once?  If so, you could try taking the shelf out, placing the cans on that shelf, and carefully putting the shelf back in.

It might not help you arrange the cans faster, but at least you will have better access to the shelf.

Comment: It probably would be faster, since the shelf could be placed on the same table as the cans, thereby cutting down the time transferring pairs of cans from the table to the fridge. However, if the carrier tipped the shelf at all while carrying it or putting it into the fridge, a LOT of cans might end up on the floor.

Comment: It certainly adds a whole other thing to think about.

Answer (score 2):

I buy cans in a 24-pack box and spaced the shelves to fit that. The whole box goes in, period. The box dispenses from the front.

Answer (score 0):

You could tune your fridge for cans if that is the main use.  Also one of these dispensers gives you first in first out so you get cold cans out first.  Vending machines use the same system because it feeds automatically.

https://www.google.fi/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Haku&q=fridge+can+dispenser+pictures

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 possible solutions for you, the first involves a binder clip, like so: [image]

The second is to build a type of Pool rack/triangle, except that it's for sodas and that it's a Rectangle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_%28billiards%29